# PHP output buffer - How to access a specific level?

Tags: php, output, buffer

When I do:

```
print_r(ob_list_handlers());
```

I get:

```
Array ( [0] => default output handler [1] => W3TC\Generic_Plugin::ob_callback [2] => Weglot::treatPage )
```

It seems that every time `ob_start()` is called it creates a new level or a new index or something in the ob stack.

How can I access the content of a specific level instead of just the default one?

Comment: I've just tried to make the question a bit clearer

Answer (score 0):

yes you are exactly right with each ob_start() you're adding one level to the stack but if you want to accumulate the outputs and later you want to use that output, i recommend using an array to put the output in. at the end of each `ob_start()` you need to close the buffer with `ob_end_...()` either you add levels to the buffer or open and close the buffer at each time so

```
$output = array();

ob_start();
echo("<h1>hello</h1>"); 
array_push($output, ob_get_contents());
ob_end_clean();

ob_start();
echo("<h3> world</h3>"); 
array_push($output, ob_get_contents());
ob_end_clean();

echo $output[0]." ".$output[1];
```

or

```
$output = array();

ob_start();
echo("<h1>hello</h1>"); 
array_push($output, ob_get_contents());

ob_start();
echo("<h3> world</h3>"); 
array_push($output, ob_get_contents());

ob_end_clean();
ob_end_clean();

echo $output[0]." ".$output[1];
```

doesn't make any difference. i hope this could help

Comment: Hi
Thansk for your reply - it's a bit clearer now and I'll see if your solution can be applied to my problem
Thanks !